# Wordpress pagination in gallery

Tags: wordpress, gallery, custom-code

I am a beginner in terms of coding. I am using elementor pro and I have a gallery and I want to insert pagination on it. With the elementor gallery elements, you can also create a multiple gallery and can filter it. But I don't want to load all of the images, so I am planning to create a pagination on it.

Does anyone here have done this?

Thank you.

I search in google and they have this loop thing, but it is only available for post or pages. Not using the gallery widget.